# run an py file with systemd

Tags: raspbian, python

i am trying to make the file to run on startup with rasbian STRETCH ,
the file need to be execute like this "configurator.py settings.conf"

with this config it doesn't work

```
[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/configurator.py
```

this is the status from the service:

```
● configurator.service - Configurator For Home Assistant
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/configurator.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-10-06 21:11:38 IDT; 3s ago
  Process: 4585 ExecStart=/home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/configurator.py (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 4585 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Oct 06 21:11:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Configurator For Home Assistant.
Oct 06 21:11:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: configurator.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Oct 06 21:11:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: configurator.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 06 21:11:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: configurator.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

any help?

Comment: You should try `env -i /home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/configurator.py`. If that fails, you need to find out which environment variables are missing and add them. Once you have them, add them to the `.service` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script exits with code 203. I haven't found a definition for this code in python but google told me that it mostly mean: "*The actual process execution failed (specifically, the exec system call). Most likely this is caused by a missing or non-accessible executable file.*". You tagged with **python** so I assume you are using python version 2. Please check if:

1. `/home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/configurator.py` is executable. If not, make it executable with `sudo chmod +x /home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/configurator.py`.
2. *configurator.py* has a shebang at first line. If not then insert at first line: `#!/usr/bin/python`.
3. you can execute the script on the command line, maybe with a specific user or as root.
4. the script needs specific environment variables.
5. the script has access to all resources it needs at startup. Maybe you have to define dependencies in your unit file, something like `After=` or `Before=` maybe with `Wants=`.
6. the script is always running in the background of if it runs only short one time at startup. Then you should use `Type=oneshot`.

You should delete the line `Type=idle` in your systemd unit file. I don't believe you really need a delayed and ordered output on a console. It seems there is no output anyway. Look at `man systemd.service` for what that's good.